# O que significa "Todos somos no mundo 'Pedro Sem'"?

Tags: expressões, significado-em-contexto, interpretação

Recentemente, lendo o poema *À Vida*, da autora portuguesa Florbela Espanca, encontrei a frase:

> Todos somos no mundo "Pedro Sem".

Pesquisei o termo "Pedro Sem/Cem" e encontrei apenas a história de um homem rico que, ao desafiar Deus, perdeu toda sua riqueza e foi "obrigado" a mendigar pelo resto de sua vida.

**Minha dúvida é** o que a escritora quis dizer ao afirmar que todos somos semelhante ao "Pedro Sem"?

**Poema:**

> É vão o amor, o ódio, ou o desdém;
> Inútil o desejo e o sentimento...
> Lançar um grande amor aos pés de alguém
> O mesmo é que lançar flores ao vento!
>
> Todos somos no mundo "Pedro Sem",
> Uma alegria é feita dum tormento,
> Um riso é sempre o eco dum lamento,
> Sabe-se lá um beijo de onde vem!
>
> A mais nobre ilusão morre... desfa-se...
> Uma saudade morta em nós renasce
> Que no mesmo momento é já perdida...
>
> Amar-te a vida inteira eu não podia,
> A gente esquece sempre o bom de um dia.
> Que queres, meu Amor, se é isto a vida!

[**Cordel sobre Pedro Sem/Cem**](http://rubi.casaruibarbosa.gov.br/bitstream/20.500.11997/1905/2/A%20vida%20de%20Pedro%20Cem.pdf)

Comment: Os poemas de Florbela, em sua maioria, são melancólicos e, quase sempre, falam, de forma triste, do amor. Lendo o cordel de Pedro Sem (não sei se é o mesmo a que ela refere-se), pude observar que ele era uma pessoa orgulhosa, vil. Ao afirmar que somos "Pedro Sem", teria ela dito que por orgulho ela perdera um amor?

Answer (score 3):

Ao utilizar esta frase, a autora refere-se ao contraste entre nossas alegrias e sofrimentos (que existem de forma indissociável, assim como a luz só existe se houver a sombra), em uma experiência cíclica. A alegria se torna em tristeza, e o prazer se origina do sofrimento.

Prestando atenção na lenda do Pedro Sem, vemos que ele era rico, vivia em luxúria, mas ao mesmo tempo não tinha título de nobre, casou-se sem amor para suprir interesses de vaidade; teve uma festa de casamento enorme, porém seus navios naufragaram e sua torre foi atingida por um raio. Em um momento era rico, e em outro pedia esmolas.
Veja que não existe felicidade sem tristeza, ou sucesso sem simultâneo fracasso. A própria "boa intenção" de boas novas são questionadas. É isso que quis dizer a autora. Veja novamente o trecho da poesia, à luz dessas informações, e veja se não somos, portanto, todos "Pedro Sem", ou seja... pessoas com felicidades temporárias, conseguidas às custas de tristeza;

Uma alegria é feita dum tormento (alegria origina de outra tristeza), um riso é sempre o eco dum lamento (a alegria é reflexo (eco) da tristeza), Sabe-se lá um beijo de onde vem! (A origem de algo bom é questionável). A autora mostra tanto um contraste entre o prazer e o sofrimento, quanto a indissociabilidade entre eles. Ao longo da história essa associação foi extensamente narrada por filósofos e poetas, particularmente podemos citar Heráclito (que desenvolveu o conceito de Devir, ou seja, a constante transformação de tudo em seu oposto), e o conceito de Dukkha, proferido por Buda, em que descreve a alegria e o sofrimento como inseparáveis.

Segundo a lenda portuguesa, como [contada na Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/$lenda-de-pedro-sem):

> "Pedro Sem era um mercador rico mas não tinha títulos de nobreza, o que muito o afetava. Possuía muitas naus na Índia e era também usurário. Vivia rodeado de luxo à custa da desgraça alheia, pois emprestava dinheiro a juros elevados.
>
> Um dia, estavam as suas naus para chegar, carregadas de especiarias e outros bens preciosos, quando a sua máxima ambição foi realizada. Casou-se com uma jovem da nobreza, em troca do perdão das dívidas do seu pai. Decorria a festa de casamento, que durou quinze dias consecutivos, quando as naus de Pedro Sem se aproximaram da barra do Douro.
>
> O arrogante mercador, acompanhado pelos seus convidados, subiu à torre do seu palácio e, confiante do seu poder, desafiou Deus, dizendo que nem o Criador o poderia fazer pobre. Nesse momento, o céu azul deu lugar a uma grande tempestade!
>
> Pedro Sem assistiu impotente ao naufrágio das suas naus. De seguida, a torre foi atingida por um raio que fez deflagrar um incêndio que destruiu todos os seus bens.
>
> Arruinado, Pedro Sem passou a pedir esmola nas ruas, lamentando-se a quem passava: "Dê uma esmolinha a Pedro Sem, que teve tudo e agora não tem...".

*Lenda de Pedro Sem* in Artigos de apoio Infopédia [em linha]. Porto: Porto Editora, 2003-2019. [consult. 2019-11-25 15:18:10]. Disponível na Internet: https://www.infopedia.pt/apoio/artigos/$lenda-de-pedro-sem

Comment: Escreves «tinha dívidas, casou-se sem amor para amortização da dívida»; mas citas a lenda que diz que ele se casou para entrar numa família nobre e assim obter o título cuja falta sempre o afetou, e em troca perdoou as dívidas do pai da noiva. Então, que dívidas tinha ele afinal?

Comment: Retificando; quem tinha dívidas era o pai da moça; Pedro Sem era comerciante, um burguês; enriquecido pelo comércio porém sem nobreza ou honra. Importante nos localizarmos nesta época de transição.

Comment: Já não está contraditório, obrigado. :)